# emerge reports "nothing to merge" for a crossdev toolchain unless executed inside chroot

Tags: linux, gentoo, cross-compilation, emerge

#### Meta

My host Gentoo installation is bootstrapped from a stage3 tarball, systemd version. My crossdev toolchain is aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu without systemd, compiled from scratch, not `--stable`. As for the C library, glibc is used in both cases. There's a warning in the handbook (somewhere around [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Cross_build_environment#Build_the_base_system)) saying that some packages might fail to build during the initial `@system` emerging, but that didn't happen to me.

All overlays from the host (`/var/db/repos/*`) are bind-mounted to corresponding directories inside the target rootfs.

The `emerge-chroot` command used inside the target is copy-pasted [from the handbook](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Cross_build_environment#Chroot_into_the_target_environment):

```
alias emerge-chroot='ROOT=/ CBUILD=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu HOSTCC=-gcc emerge'
```

#### Problem

When I do `aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-emerge -avuND @world` on the host system, emerge reports "Nothing to merge" and then exits.

```
# aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-emerge -avuND @world

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
Dependency resolution took 8.47 s.


Total: 0 packages, Size of downloads: 0 KiB

Nothing to merge; quitting.
```

However, if I chroot inside the toolchain and do `emerge-chroot -avuND @world`, it turns out that I have 90+ packages scheduled for installation - mostly perl modules and stuff like `bc`.

```
(aarch64) gentoo / # emerge-chroot -avuND @world

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
Dependency resolution took 73.04 s (backtrack: 0/10).

[ebuild  N     ] dev-util/re2c-2.2::gentoo  USE="-debug -test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-util/gtk-doc-am-1.33.2::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] net-libs/libtirpc-1.3.4:0/3::gentoo  USE="(split-usr) -kerberos -static-libs" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] net-libs/libnsl-2.0.0-r1:0/3::gentoo  USE="-static-libs" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] app-portage/elt-patches-20221210::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] app-arch/unzip-6.0_p27-r1::gentoo  USE="bzip2 (unicode) -natspec" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] app-eselect/eselect-lib-bin-symlink-0.1.1-r1::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] app-eselect/eselect-iptables-20220320::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] app-eselect/eselect-pinentry-0.7.2-r1::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-util/meson-format-array-0::gentoo  PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_11 -python3_10 -python3_12" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/installer-0.7.0::gentoo  USE="-test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_11 -pypy3 -python3_10 -python3_12" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/gpep517-15::gentoo  USE="-test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_11 -pypy3 -python3_10 -python3_12" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] app-text/build-docbook-catalog-2.4::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-libs/libxslt-1.1.38::gentoo  USE="crypt -debug -examples -python -static-libs" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_11 -python3_10 -python3_12" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] app-arch/libarchive-3.7.2:0/13::gentoo  USE="bzip2 e2fsprogs iconv lzma xattr -acl -blake2 -expat -lz4 -lzo -nettle -static-libs -verify-sig -zstd" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/flit-core-3.9.0::gentoo  USE="-test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_11 -pypy3 -python3_10 -python3_12" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] app-text/docbook-xsl-stylesheets-1.79.1-r4::gentoo  USE="-ruby" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] app-crypt/rhash-1.4.4:0/1::gentoo  USE="nls ssl -debug -static-libs" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] app-text/docbook-xsl-ns-stylesheets-1.79.1::gentoo  USE="-ruby" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/editables-0.5::gentoo  USE="-test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_11 -pypy3 -python3_10 -python3_12" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/pathspec-0.11.2::gentoo  USE="-test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_11 -pypy3 -python3_10 -python3_12" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] app-text/docbook-xml-dtd-4.1.2-r7:4.1.2::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] app-text/docbook-xml-dtd-4.2-r3:4.2::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] app-text/docbook-xml-dtd-4.5-r2:4.5::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.700.0::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-ExtUtils-CBuilder-0.280.238::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-File-Spec-3.880.0::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Scalar-List-Utils-1.630.0::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-ExtUtils-ParseXS-3.510.0::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Carp-1.540.0::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Exporter-5.770.0-r1::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Digest-MD5-2.580.100_rc::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/TimeDate-2.330.0-r1::gentoo  USE="-test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Text-CharWidth-0.40.0-r2::gentoo  USE="-test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-ExtUtils-Install-2.220.0::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-ExtUtils-Manifest-1.730.0-r2::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Getopt-Long-2.540.0::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Module-Metadata-1.0.37-r3::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Perl-OSType-1.10.0-r7::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Text-ParseWords-3.310.0-r1::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-podlators-5.10.0::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-version-0.992.900-r1::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-CPAN-Meta-YAML-0.18.0-r9::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-JSON-PP-4.160.0-r1::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Parse-CPAN-Meta-2.150.10-r7::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-IO-1.520.0::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-MIME-Base64-3.160.100_rc::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Digest-SHA-6.40.0::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] sys-apps/texinfo-7.0.3::gentoo  USE="nls standalone -static" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Locale-gettext-1.70.0-r1::gentoo  USE="-test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Digest-HMAC-1.40.0::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Pod-Parser-1.660.0::gentoo  USE="-test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/TermReadKey-2.380.0-r1::gentoo  USE="-examples -test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Text-WrapI18N-0.60.0-r2::gentoo  USE="-test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/YAML-Tiny-1.740.0::gentoo  USE="-minimal -test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/MIME-Charset-1.13.1::gentoo  USE="-test" L10N="-ja -zh" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-CPAN-Meta-2.150.10-r7::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Mozilla-CA-20999999-r1::gentoo  USE="-test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Net-SSLeay-1.920.0-r1::gentoo  USE="-examples -minimal -test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Module-Build-0.423.400::gentoo  USE="-test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] sys-apps/help2man-1.49.3::gentoo  USE="nls" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Authen-SASL-2.170.0::gentoo  USE="-kerberos -test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Unicode-LineBreak-2019.1.0::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/IO-Socket-SSL-2.83.0::gentoo  USE="-examples -idn -test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-libnet-3.150.0::gentoo  USE="ssl" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Error-0.170.290::gentoo  USE="-test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/SGMLSpm-1.1-r2::gentoo  USE="-test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/ExtUtils-CChecker-0.110.0::gentoo  USE="-test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  NS    ] dev-lang/python-3.12.0:3.12::gentoo [3.11.6:3.11::gentoo] USE="ensurepip gdbm ncurses readline sqlite ssl -bluetooth -build -debug -examples -libedit -lto -pgo -test -tk -valgrind -verify-sig" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/MailTools-2.210.0::gentoo  USE="-examples -test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/XS-Parse-Keyword-0.380.0::gentoo  USE="-test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-util/ninja-1.11.1-r2::gentoo  USE="-doc -emacs -test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-lang/tcl-8.6.13-r1:0/8.6::gentoo  USE="threads -debug" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-libs/libuv-1.46.0:0/1::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] app-text/opensp-1.5.2-r10::gentoo  USE="nls -doc -static-libs -test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Syntax-Keyword-Try-0.280.0::gentoo  USE="-test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-vcs/git-2.42.0::gentoo  USE="blksha1 curl gpg iconv nls pcre perl safe-directory webdav -cgi -cvs -doc -highlight -keyring (-mediawiki) -perforce (-selinux) -subversion -test -tk -xinetd" PYTHON_SINGLE_TARGET="python3_11 -python3_10 -python3_12" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] app-text/po4a-0.69::gentoo  USE="-test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-util/meson-1.2.2-r1::gentoo  USE="(-test)" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_11 -pypy3 -python3_10 -python3_12" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/calver-2022.06.26::gentoo  USE="-test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_11 -pypy3 -python3_10 -python3_12" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/cython-3.0.2-r1::gentoo  USE="-debug -doc -test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_11 -pypy3 -python3_10 -python3_12" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/markupsafe-2.1.3::gentoo  USE="-debug -test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_11 -pypy3 -python3_10 -python3_12" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/pygments-2.16.1::gentoo  USE="-test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_11 -pypy3 -python3_10 -python3_12" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/jinja-3.1.2::gentoo  USE="-doc -examples -test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_11 -pypy3 -python3_10 -python3_12" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/pluggy-1.3.0::gentoo  USE="-test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_11 -pypy3 -python3_10 -python3_12" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/trove-classifiers-2023.9.19::gentoo  USE="-test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_11 -pypy3 -python3_10 -python3_12" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-libs/jsoncpp-1.9.5:0/25::gentoo  USE="-doc -test" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/lxml-4.9.3-r2::gentoo  USE="threads -debug -doc -examples -test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_11 -pypy3 -python3_10 -python3_12" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/docutils-0.20.1-r1::gentoo  PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_11 -pypy3 -python3_10 -python3_12" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/hatchling-1.18.0::gentoo  USE="-test" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_11 -pypy3 -python3_10 -python3_12" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-util/cmake-3.27.7::gentoo  USE="ncurses (-dap) -doc -emacs -gui (-qt6) -test -verify-sig" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] sys-devel/bc-1.07.1-r6::gentoo  USE="readline -libedit -static" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] app-alternatives/bc-0::gentoo  USE="gnu -gh" 0 KiB

Total: 93 packages (92 new, 1 in new slot), Size of downloads: 0 KiB

Would you like to merge these packages? [Yes/No]
```

I tried to explicitly emerge one of the packages from the list using the host part of the toolchain - it was a success.

```
# aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-emerge -avuND dev-util/re2c
```

Then I chrooted back into the toolchain rootfs, executed `emerge-chroot -avuND @world` - and `dev-util/re2c` wasn't there anymore, which leaves the total of 92 packages pending:

```
 # emerge-chroot -avuND @world

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
Dependency resolution took 72.06 s (backtrack: 0/10).

[ebuild  N     ] dev-util/gtk-doc-am-1.33.2::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] net-libs/libtirpc-1.3.4:0/3::gentoo  USE="(split-usr) -kerberos -static-libs" 0 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] net-libs/libnsl-2.0.0-r1:0/3::gentoo  USE="-static-libs" 0 KiB
...
Total: 92 packages (91 new, 1 in new slot), Size of downloads: 0 KiB

Would you like to merge these packages? [Yes/No]
```

I want to build as much as possible using the cross-compiler. Obviously, at least some packages from the above list can be built with a cross-compiler.

Any ideas how to... synchronize things between `aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-emerge` and `emerge-chroot`? I know I can probably just grep and sed package names out of the `emerge-chroot` output and feed it to `aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-emerge` on the host later, but something tells me that's not the right way to do it.

Comment: The alias `emerge-chroot` can only be used inside  of the `chroot`, but you are running plain `emerge` from outside the `chroot`.  The alias properly passes the needed environment variables through the string expansion of `CBUILD=$(portageq envvar CHOST) HOSTCC=$CBUILD-gcc` to the proper bash config file.  What is the output of `echo $CBUILD` after setting it in the alias?  Compare the output to `aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-emerge`  Are both compiler names equal??